# How to run whichever function is bound to a certain key

Tags: key-bindings

There are a lot of occasions where, by default, the key-binding `C-c C-c` does something useful - e.g. in org-mode or magit. I would like to take whatever function `C-c C-c` runs, and bind that function to something like `F8`, without having to know what specific function is being called under the hood.

Thus: how can I take an existing key-binding, obtain the function which that key-binding would run, and then simply run that function?

(I'm aware it would take me 5 min to just make a list of functions that I'm interested in, and bind them appropriately in the respective modes - but I would nevertheless like to know how to achieve the above)

Comment: Note that `C-c C-c` in org-mode runs a generic command (`org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c`) that then dispatches to different functions, depending on context. The solutions below will get you to the top-level command dispatcher, but if you want to get to the lower level dispatched function, you will have to read the `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trivially, with a keyboard macro:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") (kbd "C-c C-c"))
```

n.b. That's not binding to a function; it's making <kbd><f8></kbd> issue the key sequence <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>, which will in turn call whatever command it is bound to.

However as the <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> sequence is reserved for major modes (refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Key Binding Conventions`), you can trust that the local keymap will contain the binding of interest, and so you could use that to bind <kbd><f8></kbd> to the same command.

Here's an example I use to make <kbd>RET</kbd> do whatever <kbd>M-j</kbd> is bound to in any programming major mode.

```el
(defun my-coding-config ()
  "Common behaviours for programming."
  (local-set-key (kbd "RET") (key-binding (kbd "M-j"))))

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'my-coding-config)
```

Answer (score 3):

To find which command `C-c C-c` runs, you can use `key-binding`, e.g.,

```
(key-binding (kbd "C-x C-f"))
;; => find-file
```

To run an interactive command from Lisp, you can use `call-interactively`, e.g.,

```
(call-interactively #'find-file)
```

(`funcall` won't work sometimes since it doesn't take care of the interactive spec.)

So maybe the following does what you want

```el
(defun your-ctrl-c-ctrl-c ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((command (key-binding (kbd "C-c C-c"))))
    (when command
      (call-interactively command))))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") #'your-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
```

Comment: Nitpick: `call-interactively` only works on commands which are also functions.  So in general you should rather use `execute-command` which should work for any command, whether it's a function or a key-sequence.